# Pipe files to uglifyjs - from Powershell

Tags: node.js, powershell, command-line-arguments, npm, uglifyjs

I would like to pipe my .js files to uglifyjs using windows powershell.

This will not work:

```
dir .\build -filter *.js | uglifyjs > bundle.js
```

From the [uglifyjs2 docs](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) i can see that uglifyjs takes 2 parameters:

`uglifyjs [input files] [options]`

I have learned that i can use the pipe operator on functions with one parameter without modifications. But **how should i handle 2 parameters**?

Also, uglifyjs will write the result to STDOUT. That means that i can simply use > to write it to a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like uglifyjs can process multiple filenames or STDIN.

So I think you have two options:

**Option 1 - Pipe the contents of the file into uglifyjs**

```
dir .\build -filter *.js | Get-Content | uglifyjs -o bundle.js
```

**Option 2 - Pass the filenames into uglifyjs**

```
$files = (dir .\build -filter *.js | select -expandproperty Name) -Join " "    
uglifyjs $files -o bundle.js
```

Comment: @ThomasDeutsch I don't have uglifyjs so the above is untested.